# Interface cell not supported system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am getting this error while trying to compile some files.

Error-[NYI-NS] Not Yet Implemented
  The following feature is not yet supported: Replacing interface cell in 
  logical library not yet supported

My files:
monitor_interface.sv

```
interface monitor_if(
input logic a,
input logic b
);
endinterface

bind TB monitor_if
mon_if1(
...
);
```

File 2 (which has "`include monitor_interface.sv")

```
virtual monitor_if if1;
//passes this interface to another module.
```

I don't understand what is going on. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

[Edit]
top.sv

```
virtual monitor_interface monitor_if;
initial begin
 ... 
end
monitor mon1(monitor_if);
```

monitor.sv:

```
module monitor (monitor_if);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Not Yet Implemented" message usually means the tool recognizes what you are trying to do, but does not support it, most likely related to the bind construct. You should have gotten a line number pointing to the exact spot.

Is the bind statement inside another module? or outside of any construct.

The problem could also be you made a mistake somewhere and the compiler did the best it could do understand, but it is giving you an unrelated error. where is the `` `include `` statement?

Comment: I realized that I had included this monitor_interface.sv in 2 place. The file where the monitor module is defined and in the top module. I included an ifndef statement in the beginning and it solved the problem. The bind statement is in the same file as the interface. As an aside, can I ask if I can pass a virtual interface of type monitor_if instantiated in the top file to the monitor module? I tried this and am getting an "Error-[ELAB-ICIP] Illegally connected interface port" error. (I am running out of space so am editing the question instead.)

Comment: You do not normally use virtual interfaces to connect interfaces, but the actual interface. Probably worth a separate question. Can you accept this answer and start with a new question.